# ExtJs Framework with Flex

Tags: apache-flex, extjs

How to embed the Flex Grid in ExtJs framework.

Thanks,
Ravi

Comment: If you are using the Flex grid then you will have to compile it to a SWF. Then you can embed it just like any other flash content.

Comment: Todd, Can you please provide me a code for embed swf file into ExtJs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I search in google, i got a code.

Please check it and let me know if i am wrong.

**

```
 var mclock;   
 document.write(   
   mclock=new Ext.ux.Media.Flash(

       {mediaCfg:{   
                 url    : 'clock.swf'   
                 ,id     : 'inlineClock'   
                 ,style  : {display:'inline',width:'100px',height:'80px'} 
                 ,start    : true
                 ,loop     : true
                 ,controls :false
                 ,params: {   
                           wmode     :'transparent'   
                           ,scale     :'exactfit'   
                           ,salign    :'t'   
                          }   
                 }     
        }

      )
```

);

**